# traceroute going to wrong gateway

Tags: networking

i have a server for which the traceroute result is different when -I (icmp) is used.
The correct route for destination 10.1.1.1/32 is already added

e.g. the routing table on host looks something like

```
10.1.1.1 mask 255.255.255.255 nexthop 10.10.10.10
0.0.0.0/0 nexthop 10.10.10.1
```

```
traceroute -I 10.1.1.1 goes to 10.10.10.10
traceroute 10.1.1.1 goes to 10.10.10.1
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you use the `ip route` command and post your actual routing table, and copy+paste some of the examples from the command you're running?

Comment: Have you tried adding the interface to the route?
I had an similar issue when adding the route without interface